# Cannot remove this column, because it is part of an expression

Tags: c#

I have a datatable and I am masking one column by adding new column name as MASKEDSSN. 
It has been masked. But i need to Remove Old Column name SSN. While Removing it throws an error as

> Cannot remove this column, because it is part of an expression: 
>           MaskedSSN = 'XXX-XX-'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(SSN, System.String),6,4).

Code:

```
 DataTable employeeTable = new DataTable();
 employeeTable.Rows.Add("123455789");
 employeeTable.Rows.Add("123447789");
 employeeTable.Rows.Add("823456719");
 employeeTable.Columns.Add("SSN");

 int index = employeeTable.Columns["SSN"].Ordinal;
 employeeTable.Columns.Add("MaskedSSN", typeof(string));
 employeeTable.Columns["MaskedSSN"].Expression = "'XXX-XX- 
     '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(SSN, System.String),6,4)";
 DataTable newsss = new DataTable();

 newsss = employeeTable.Copy();
 newsss.AcceptChanges();
 newsss.Columns.RemoveAt(index);
 newsss.Columns.Remove("SSN");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions, or computed columns, relies on the source column to have the data in, because it is referencing the data, it doesn't COPY the data and then mask it.

So if your original column data changes, the new column will automatically have the same value.

When you understand this dependency, you will realize that you can't just remove the source column, because if you do, you will have a null reference exception happening. Think of it as excel spreadsheet. Column A has a value, Column B uses Column A's value to determine a percentage (or show it in a currency format). If you delete Column A, Columb B will immediately get an error (#REF! or something)

Your question on CodeProject has more detail, which would be appreciated on StackOverflow too: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1272445/Cannot-remove-this-column-because-it-is-part-of-an

In there, you show you try to copy the table, and then remove the column from it, while still having the expression, which results in an error.

Hopefully my explanation highlights the dependency between a column and a computed column/expression.

I would suggest formatting the data in the front-end (that's why we have front-end), or, if it's part of an API, format it in the SQL output.

Any input can also be masked so that data is inserted correctly BEFORE having to read it out anywhere.

You can mask manually using `string.Format` (note, below might not compile, I leave it to you to figure out)

```
 string result = string.Format("XXX-XX-{0}", SSNColumnValue.Substring(4,6));
```

Hope this helps guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You are using Expression syntax to build MaskedSSN

```
employeeTable.Columns["MaskedSSN"].Expression = "'XXX-XX- 
 '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(SSN, System.String),6,4)";
```

If you make masking manually with AddRow, you can delete old SSN Column.

**Edit**

```
Func<string, string> MaskingFnc = (string ssnParam) => string.Format("XXX-XX-{0}", ssnParam.Substring(4,6));

DataTable employeeTable = new DataTable();
employeeTable.Columns.Add("SSN")
employeeTable.Columns.Add("SSNMasked")
employeeTable.Rows.Add("123455789", MaskingFnc("123455789"));
employeeTable.Rows.Add("123447789", MaskingFnc("123447789"));
employeeTable.Rows.Add("823456719", MaskingFnc("823456719"));
```